# Query All Pages Based on Compoent's Resource Type

Tags: adobe, aem, jcr, jcr-sql2

I have this `JCR-SQL2` query to **get all pages that have a specific component**:

> SELECT page.* FROM [cq:Page] AS page INNER JOIN [nt:base] AS component
> ON ISCHILDNODE(component,page) WHERE component.[sling:resourceType]
> ='/libs/wcm/foundation/components/image' AND  page.[jcr:path] LIKE '/content'

It compiles properly but no results were returned. I also tried to change the component resource type but nothing got returned when it should. I was wondering if there's anything wrong with my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT page.* FROM [cq:Page] AS page INNER JOIN [nt:base] AS component 
ON ISDESCENDANTNODE(component, page) 
WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE(page, "/search/in/path") 
AND component.[sling:resourceType] = "/resource/path"
```